# How will Russians get reliable information?

Tags: russian-federation, media, freedom-of-information

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_freedom_in_Russia#:%7E:text=Article%2029(5)%20of%20the,Censorship%20shall%20be%20prohibited.%22):

> *Article 29(5) of the Constitution of Russia states, "The freedom of the mass media shall be guaranteed. Censorship shall be prohibited."*

[New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/03/04/world/europe/russia-censorship-media-crackdown.htmlhttps://), March 4, 2022:

> Russia clamped down harder Friday on news and free speech than at any time in President Vladimir Putin’s 22 years in power, blocking access to *Facebook* and major foreign news outlets, and enacting a law to punish anyone spreading “false information” about its Ukraine invasion with up to 15 years in prison.
>
> The crackdown comes as the Kremlin scrambles to contain discontent over the war and to control the narrative as Russia faces its most severe economic crisis in decades as a result of this week’s crushing Western sanctions. Fearing prosecution, more independent Russian news outlets shut down on Friday, and the *BBC* said it had suspended all of its operations in Russia.

How will Russians get reliable information? The Wikipedia article at the top states, again:

> ***"The freedom of the mass media shall be guaranteed. Censorship shall be prohibited."***

Non-mentioned sources:

[Vox](https://www.vox.com/recode/22962274/russia-block-facebook-restrict-twitter-putin-censorship-ukraine)

[New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/03/03/world/europe/russia-ukraine-propaganda-censorship.htmlhttps://)

[Amnesty](https://www.amnesty.org/en/latest/news/2022/02/russia-kremlin-censors-media-and-disperses-protesters-opposed-to-ukraine-invasion/)

Comment: The quote in bold is sourced from "Article 29(5) of the Constitution of Russia", are you asking how Russia has explained that guarantee?

Comment: @JJJ yes,in a nutshell.

Comment: This question kind of just seems like a "look at this article that I agree with" question.

Comment: I saw this question in the close queue. I won't vote to close, but I still think that the question is poorly asked. It needs more details about what is asked. Furthermore, does the constitution refer to the Russian media or the international media?

Comment: You don't need to copy-paste entire articles about Russian censorship into your question. Just one or two paragraphs is enough.

Comment: @F1Krazy oh okay ,people were saying there wasn't enough info,so I added more.

Comment: I just realized that this question was closed for "discrediting" Vladimir Putin. Why exactly shouldn't I discredit him?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to the "fog of war", if is unlikely that anybody is getting reliable information about the "course of military actions".

Other than that, Russians can still open The Guardian or Hacker News, shrug and close the tab. They can also read any of dozens of military news channels in Telegram and often have no choice but to stumble on Ukrainian propaganda/psy ops.

Comment: They can even read the Guardian and Hacker News. Though I do not know why one would want to get information about international matters from Hacker News.

Comment: The chief issue for Russians wanting to read some press coverage in English is not knowing where to look, really.